# Modelsim: How to disable SDF timing check for certain module in the design?

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I'm using Modelsim/Questasim to run a Verilog gate level simulation. Some synchronizers are added to my original design since it uses two clocks with different frequencies. I want to disable timing check only for these synchronizers.

I want to use the Modelsim/Questasim  "tcheck_set" command but this command is not recognized by the Modelsim/Questasim TCL interrupter.

Can anyone tell me how to use "tcheck_set" in latest Modelsim/Questasim?

Answer (score 1):

from modelsim vsim "do file" script:

```
tcheck_set {/tb/dut/U1} OFF

run -all
```

This will disable all timing checks in instance U1.

Be careful if the instance name has special characters like "\", for example:

```
VSIM> tcheck_set  {/tb_top/U1/\tp_mux_pad[15]} OFF
# ERROR: instance "\tp_mux_pad[15]"  not found

VSIM> tcheck_set {/tb_top/U1/*tp_mux_pad[15]} OFF
# /tb/U1/\tp_mux_pad[15]/U0/U1
# 1 ( WIDTH (posedge E) ) MsgOff XOff
# 2 ( WIDTH (negedge E) ) MsgOff XOff
# 3 ( WIDTH (posedge D) ) MsgOff XOff
# 4 ( WIDTH (negedge D) ) MSgOff XOff
```

Not really sure how to escape the "\" character, so I used the asterisk wildcard character '*' instead... but the curly braces "{ }" around the instance path works to escape the TCL special characters of square brace "[ ]" and parenthesis "( )" so that it gets passed to the tcheck_set command unchanged.

Another example:

```
VSIM> find instances {tb_top/U1/*tp_mux_pad* }
# {/tb_top/U1/\tp_mux_pad[15]/U0/U0  (IOPAD_TRI)} {/tb_top/U1/\tp_mux_pad[15]/U0/U1  (IOTRI_OB_EB)}
```

---

**Update:**

I figured out how to escape the backspace character '\'.
The backslash in a signal name represents a gatelevel netlist standard that allows gatelevel signals to have special characters in the signal name like, ". / [ ] ( )", etc..  Whenever you see a backslash character in a signal name, then all characters are treated like "A-Z" characters including normally special characters until the signal name is terminated with a space character. (sometimes you need to escape the final space character in the signal name with a backslash also, but in our case we are using TCL curly brackets which treats all characters inside the curly braces as literal characters including the space character at the end.  Thus, the example becomes:

```
VSIM> check_set {/tb_top/U1/\tp_mux_pad[15]/U0/U0 } ON
# /tb_top/U1/\tp_mux_pad[15]/U0/U0 :
# 1 ( WIDTH (posedge E) ) MsgOn XOn
# 2 ( WIDTH (negedge E) ) MsgOn XOn
# 3 ( WIDTH (posedge D) ) MsgOn XOn
# 4 ( WIDTH (negedge D) ) MsgOn XOn
```

Here, "\tp_mux_pad[15]/U0/U0 " is the entire instance name, where the normal meaning of the special characters, ". / [ ] ( )", are treated like ordinary A-Z characters when the backslash '\' is present in the signal path until a space character is found in the signal name.

```
# CASE 1:            
#
#  SPACE AT END OF SIGNAL NAME REQUIRED WHEN BACKSLASH CHARACTER
#  EXAMPLE:  check_set {/tb_top/U1/\tp_mux_pad[15]/U0/U0 } ON
#                                                       ^space
# CASE 2:
#
#  SPACE AT END OF SIGNAL NOT REQUIRED IF THERE IS NO BACKSLASH CHARACTER)
#  EXAMPLE:  check_set {/tb_top/U1} ON
#
```